# g++ -Wall -g -c main.cpp -lGL -lGLU -lglfw3 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi - Could you explain this command?

Tags: c++, g++, codelite

I've got a really specific problem but I'm relatively new to C++. Could you explain me each part of the command?

If you can, please also explain me, where to paste those options in CodeLite

[image]

Comment: man g++ (or via internet looking for manpages (linux))

Comment: Did you look up help/man pages of g++?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the [official manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0/gcc_3.html) already explains each of those options and parameters in depth.

Comment: Probably, you do not need to add these options to CodeLite, most of them are probably on by default. Only the libraries, but that would go somewhere in the **Linker** settings.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ At least the `-lXXX` ones are relatively difficult to find there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure:

- `g++`: This is the C++ compiler from the GCC (GNU Compiler Collection).
- `-Wall`: Switch on all usual warnings, that is the compiler will warn about a lot of things that, while not being technically an error, as suspicious.
- `-g`: Generate debugging information, you know, to be able to use a debugger.
- `-c`: Compile only, that will generate an object file, not an executable. You are expected to run the linker later to build the actual executable.
- `main.cpp`: Your source file.
- `-lGL -lGLU -lglfw3 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi`: Those are libraries. Each of the `-lXXX` will link to a library named `libXXX.so` or `libXXX.a`.

Note that your command, as is, makes no sense, because you are setting `-c` to compile only, not linking, but you are adding libraries, and those are used only for linking. So the libraries are simply ignored.

For more information, see `man g++`, `info g++` and http://gcc.gnu.org.